# Javascript factorial program

Tags: math, factorial

Why does this program not work?

This is an exercise from http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-factorialize-a-number

```
function factorialize(num)
{
  for (i=num; i>0; i--)
  {
   num*= num[i];
  }
  return num;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Look at the errors in your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit too late...

You just should use `num *= i;` instead of `num *= num[i]`. What your code did is trying to access the property `i` of the number object `num`, which is undefined.

Also you should change your loop initialization to `for(var i = num - 1; i > 1; i--)` to just create a local variable and not a global one. Also, multiplying `num` by `num` (first loop cycle) would give incorrect results. And last but not least, multiplying by 1 (last loop cycle) is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You multiply with `num[i]` but num isn't an array (that is where you get the error). Also, your first iteration would multiply 5*5 which is wrong, it should be 5*4, so we start at `i=num-1`. and also, i>1 is enough, the `num *= 1`is pretty pointless.

this works:

```
function factorialize(num)
{
  for (i=num-1; i>1; i--)
  {
   num*= i;
  }
  return num;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Feinmann can achieve this answer using below recursive function.

```
function factorialize(num) {
 if(num==0) {
  return 1;
 }
 return num * factorialize(num-1);
}
```